# Storing **array into another array (function) in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

My task is to enter a sentence and every 2nd word is to be stored into a second array. I managed to send the array into a function, but now I don't know how to store words with `strcpy`.

First array is `mat1` and second array is `mat2`.

```
void function(char **mat1, char *mat2, int n, int *j)
{
    int i, j2=0;
    printf("\n");

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%s ", mat1[i]);
        printf("\n");

        if(i==0 || i%2==0)
        {
            mat2[j2]=(char*)malloc(10);
            strcpy(&mat2, mat1);
            j2++;
        }
    }
}
```

In `main`, I did this:

```
char *mat1[10], mat2[10], mat3[10];
mat1[i]=(char*)malloc(10);

scanf("%s", mat1[i]);

function( mat1,&mat2[0], n, &j);
```

I'm not sure if I need to malloc `mat2` and then to do something with `strcpy`. I need to return `mat2` and `printf` words in main.

Comment: What is `mat2` in main?

Comment: char *mat1[10], mat2[10], mat3[10];

Comment: `strcpy(&mat2, mat1);` is bad because it will write the string to the pointer variable, breaks the pointer value, and have a risk of buffer overrun.

Comment: Mat2 returns some random values

Comment: The first thing to do is to change type of `mat2` (both in main and `function`) to deal with array of string pointers.

Comment: char *mat2 in main, and i need then to alocate it in function and recieve it in function with **mat2?

Comment: Note: `i%2==0` will be true if `i==0` is true.

Comment: What your function should do? Does it  take any sentence and store the second word of that sentence in  string `mat2` or store the second word in array of strings `mat2`. i.e. every time you call `function` , it should store the second word in the array `mat2` with new index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you should change type types of `mat2` to which are similar to ones of `mat1`.

Then, allocate buffers and copy strings using array access to their elements.

```
void function(char **mat1, char **mat2, int n, int *j)
{
    int i, j2=0;
    printf("\n");

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {


        printf("%s ", mat1[i]);
        printf("\n");


        if(i==0 || i%2==0)
        {
            mat2[j2]=(char*)malloc(10);
            strcpy(mat2[j2], mat1[i]);
            j2++;
        }
    }
    *j = j2; /* probably you want this */
}
```

```
char *mat1[10], *mat2[10], mat3[10];
function( mat1, mat2, n, &j);
```